# MySQL complex order by Query equivalent in Yii2 Active record

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I need to order a table data by `status` field but also I want to show some rows first, which have a certain `status`.

Currently I can achieve this using MySQL like this:

```
SELECT status FROM item
ORDER BY status NOT LIKE '%order-status%',  status
```

So all the items have `order-status` order status will show first and then others order by the status.

But I am unable to achieve this in Yii2 Active Record. I tried to write something like:

```
$query->orderBy(['not like', 'item.status', 'order-status']);
$query->orderBy(['item.status' => SORT_ASC]);
```

But it it is not correct. Is there any way to achieve this in Active Record?

Comment: Use [yii\db\Expression](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression) in orderBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `yii\db\Expression` to create a custom `order by` clause. The query for your requirement will be like this:

```
$query->orderBy(new yii\db\Expression("status NOT LIKE '%order-status%',  status"))
```

This parameter passed in `Expression` instance will be used directly by Yii 2 query builder. For more details you can read the [`Expression` documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression).

Answer (score 0):

You can use string in `orderBy`, like that:

```
$query->orderBy("status NOT LIKE '%order-status%',  status");
```

or

```
$query->orderBy("status NOT LIKE '%order-status%'")
     ->addOrderBy('status');
```

Helpful Link: [db-query-builder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#order-by)